# Solving $(p-1)(p^{12}+p^{13}+\cdots+p^{41})$ for a given $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $p$ is a solution for the equation $x^6-2=0$, then how to find $$(p-1)(p^{12}+p^{13}+\cdots+p^{41})$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply that out to find that it folds up like a telescope:
$$(p-1)(p^{12}+\cdots+p^{41})=p^{13}-p^{12}-p^{13}+\cdots+p^{41}+p^{42}-p^{41}=p^{42}-p^{12}.$$
I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: I like your solution better than mine, so deleting.

Answer (score 1):

$$p^{12}+\ldots +p^{41}=p^{12} \cdot \frac{p^{30}-1}{p-1}$$

Now $p^{6}=2$ so $p^{30}=2^{5}=32$ and $p^{12}=2^{2}=4$

So: $$p^{12}\cdot \frac {p^{30}-1}{p-1}=4 \cdot \frac {32-1}{p-1}=\frac{4 \cdot 31}{p-1}$$

So the final answer:

$$(p-1) \cdot \frac{124}{p-1}=124.$$